# Is the last scene in The Last: Naruto the Movie the end of Naruto?

Tags: naruto

At the end of *The Last: Naruto the Movie*, after Naruto and Hinata got married and Hinata gave birth to two kids, is that the end of Naruto? Will they create a sequel to the story?

Comment: `last episode` which episode

Answer (score 4):

There's currently an on-going manga about a future story titled [***Naruto Gaiden: The Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring***](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Gaiden:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring).

At the end of *The Last: Naruto the Movie*, there is an announcement for the next movie called [***Boruto: Naruto the Movie***](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Boruto:_Naruto_the_Movie). (Thanks to Ankit Sharma for pointing this out)

Comment: "other media", have you forgot to mention Boruto: Naruto the Movie

Comment: You're right, it totally slipped my mind, Editted it

Comment: Would like to add that Gaiden and the Boruto Movie are apart of the much larger [Naruto Project](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Naruto_Project) or otherwise titled Naruto's New Era Opening Project (the icon shown seems to depict Minato, Naruto and Boruto), and the Wiki says and that the 29th of July a "secret" will be revealed